# Why seize queue cant be zero in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

Let's imagine a situation where we have a queue positioned before the seize block, and this queue has the timeout property activated.

In such cases, it is important to note that the seizure queue cannot be reduced to zero. The seize queue always has a minimum capacity of 1. If the seize queue capacity were set to 1, one agent would be taken out of the timeout property of the original queue and placed directly into the seize queue.

This behavior is generally not desirable, particularly when dealing with a large number of agents or running the simulation for extended periods, such as years, to collect the statistics, especially for the timeout property of the original queue.

[image]

So how can I avoid having an agent in the seize queue, or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually avoid having agents in the `Seize` queue by using a `Hold` block upstream and only releasing agents into the `Seize` block if its queue is empty.